# What is the correct way to import modules/packages for Python projects with unit tests?

Tags: python, package, python-unittest

I have the following directory structure:

```
|_ director_script.py
|_ app/
      |_ __init__.py
      |_ ParentClass.py
      |_ my_module/
                 |_ __init__.py
                 |_ MyClass.py
                 |_ MyClassTestCase.py
```

In my `director_script.py` I use `MyClass` and when I run `python director_script.py` the scripts run as expected without any error. However, when I cd into `my_module` folder and run the unit tests using `python -m unittest MyClassTestCase`, I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
```

This caused by the import statement in `MyClass.py` that is

`from app.ParentClass import ParentClass`

This import is fine when I run it from `director_script.py` and only happens with the unit test.

Answer (score 2):

You should run from outside the app folder, any folder that has an `__init__.py` is a submodule in python. If you set the current working directory to my_module, it cannot see the app module, unless you have the folder path corresponding to the app folder set in the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable

Answer (score 0):

Add a file called `__init__.py` into the top floder

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a kludge, but this is how I usually do it:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../app')
```

Or under Windows:

```
sys.path.append('..\\app')
```

This needs to come before your module import, of course.